# MongoDB benchmarking inserts

Tags: mongodb, performance, performance-testing, database-performance, nosql

I am trying to benchmark MongoDB with the JS harness. I am trying to do inserts. The example given [in mongo website](https://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/reference/js-benchmarking-harness/).

However, I am trying an insert operation, which works totally fine, but gives out wrong queries/sec.

```
ops = [{op: "insert", ns: "benchmark.bench", safe: false, doc: {"a": 1}}]
```

The above works fine. Then, I have run the following in mongo shell:

```
for ( x = 1; x<=128; x*=2){
    res = benchRun( { parallel : x ,
                      seconds : 5 ,
                      ops : ops
                    } )
    print( "threads: " + x + "\t queries/sec: " + res.query )
}
```

It gives out:

```
threads: 1   queries/sec: 0
threads: 2   queries/sec: 0
threads: 4   queries/sec: 0
threads: 8   queries/sec: 0
threads: 16  queries/sec: 0
threads: 32  queries/sec: 1.4
threads: 64  queries/sec: 0
threads: 128     queries/sec: 0
```

I dont understand why the queries/sec is 0 and not a single doc has been inserted. Is this right was testing performance for inserts?

Comment: There are no errors or warnings thrown at all.

Comment: Take a look at the insert in the [dynamic values](https://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/reference/js-benchmarking-harness/#dynamic-values) example. You don't have the right notation for an insert. Also, don't benchmark with benchrun.

Comment: @wdberkeley: What then is better way for benchmarking?

Comment: For generic benchmarking, you can use YCSB. If you are benchmarking for a particular use case, like a proposed application, then there's no substitute for just actually trying out a realistic workload on a data model designed to meet the use case. Other benchmarks may not be that relevant to a specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I just encountered a similar problem.

Try replacing your print statement with `printjson(res)`.
You will see that res has the following fields:

```
{
    "note" : "values per second",
    "errCount" : NumberLong(0),
    "trapped" : "error: not implemented",
    "insertLatencyAverageMicros" : 8.173300153139357,
    "totalOps" : NumberLong(130600),
    "totalOps/s" : 25366.173139864142,
    "findOne" : 0,
    "insert" : 25366.173139864142,
    "delete" : 0,
    "update" : 0,
    "query" : 0,
    "command" : 0
}
```

As you can see, the query count is 0, hence when you print `res.query` it gives 0. To get the number of insert operations per second you would want to print `res.insert`. I believe `res.query` corresponds to the "find" operation.